# Collision detection in cocos2dx Using Box2D or chipmunk

Tags: cocos2d-x, box2d, collision, chipmunk

I am making a game in which multiple character fire towards each other and on hitting the fire they will act with different animations like: blast, bounce, blur and so on. For now the thing where i am stuck is that while fire is traveling how will we check that its intersecting with other objects of not? I mean run animations only on targeted characters.

Answer (score 0):

You could save your objects that want to check in a vector and schedule an update in your scene that checks if they collide.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer for **Box2D**.

1. Create a body def for each of the objects you are firing. Using some of the code below. Make sure you change shapes to fit what you need. Pixel to meter ratio I set to 32.0 in my code.

   ```
   b2BodyDef bulletDef;
   bulletDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
   bulletDef.position.Set(startPositionX / Pixel_To_Meter_Ratio,
                          startPositionY / Pixel_To_Meter_Ratio);

   auto b2PolygonShape bulletShape;
   bulletShape.SetAsBox(bulletWidth / Pixel_To_Meter_Ratio,
                        bulletHeight / Pixel_To_Meter_Ratio);

   auto bulletBody = physicsWorld->CreateBody(bulletDef)
   ```
2. Apply velocity to the body def in the position that you want the bullet to go.

   ```
   bulletBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(b2Vec(bulletDirectionX, 
                                  bulletDirectionY),  
                                  physicsBody->GetPosition(), 
                                  true);
   ```
3. Add a contact listener to the physics world that inherits from b2ContactListener

   ```
   // Node that manages the physics world from box2d
   class PhysicsNode : public b2ContactListener
   {
    void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact);
   }

   // register this listener with the box2d world
   auto physicsWorld = new b2World(b2Vec2(0, -9.8f));
   physicsWorld ->SetContactListener(this);
   ```
4. Implement the BeginContact function and handle the collision in there.

   ```
   void PhysicsNode::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
   { 
       // Get the physics bodies
       auto objectOne = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();
       auto objectTwo = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();

       // Cast to the type you set as your user data
       auto collidableOne = static_cast<Collidable*>(objectOne->GetUserData());
       auto collidableTwo = static_cast<Collidable*>(objectTwo->GetUserData());

       // Handle your collisions. Apply blur/explode/whatever you need
       collidableOne->handleCollision(collidableTwo->isReactableCollision());
       collidableTwo->handleCollision(collidableOne->isReactableCollision());
   }
   ```

I hope this helps. This is what I use to achieve the functionality you are looking for.